Sourcemap enabled but stacktrace is only showing me the line + column number in the *.chunk.js file
I am getting an error from New Relic but it collects the stack trace from the bundle. I have enabled the source maps and can see the source code in the Chrome when I do Ctrl-P in the Source tab.
How do I trace back this line + column number in the *chunk.js into the actual source file where the error occurred?
Stack trace:
Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.\n    at ps (https://xyz.com.au/static/js/2.987bf123.chunk.js:2:10986875)

